# permissions issue when running bokeh server from supervisor

Tags: python, flask, permissions, supervisord, bokeh

I have a web application that employs the `bokeh` plotting engine. I have created an interactive plotting app based of of their "[Stocks Example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/server_gallery/stocks_server.html)"

I have it running successfully on my development machine. On my application server, I am running everything from `supervisor` (`supervisorctl`).

I am using `redis` as the backend.

I am having a permissions issue based on who is "driving" the various applications. When I try to access the application on the server, my traceback shows a directory creation permission problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... flask / wsgi stuff ...
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 755, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/webapp/mod_performance/plotting_views.py", line 53, in data_viz
    bs = make_bokeh_session()
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/webapp/mod_performance/plotting_views.py", line 27, in make_bokeh_session
    b_session.login(un, pw)
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 244, in login
    self.save()
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 180, in save
    data = self.load_dict()
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 151, in load_dict
    configfile = self.configfile
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 148, in configfile
    return join(self.configdir, "config.json")
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 138, in configdir
    makedirs(bokehdir)
  File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.bokeh'
```

I placed a print statement in my `flask` view to show who the current user is (using `os.getegid()`)

```
from bokeh.session import Session as bSession
...
def make_bokeh_session():
    print 'bokeh session group!!!!!!!! {}'.format(os.getegid())
    print 'bokeh session user!!!!!!!! {}'.format(os.path.expanduser('~'))
    un = current_user.username
    pw = current_app.config['BOKEH_SESSION_PW']
    b_session = bSession(root_url=bokeh_url, load_from_config=False)
    try:
        b_session.login(un, pw)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        b_session.register(un, pw)
        b_session.login(un, pw)
    output_server('ers_plots')
    return b_session
```

The print statement gives shows group id of `1000` (my `webdev` user who runs basically everything), although the `os.expanduser('~')` shows the user as root.

See below for the `supervisor` configuration snippets.

```
[program:bokehservergo]
directory = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/webapp/mod_performance
command = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/bin/bokeh-server --script=plotting_app.py --backend=redis --no-start-redis -m
user=webdev
...
```

The webapp is run with the `uwsgi emperor`

```
[program:uwsgi_emperor_go]
command = /usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
user=webdev
...
```

And the redis runner

```
[program:redisgo]
command=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf
user=webdev
...
```

The relavent code from `bokeh/session.py` (`makedirs` is actually throwing the traceback)

```
@property
    def configdir(self):
        """ filename where our config are stored. """
        if self._configdir:
            return self._configdir
        bokehdir = join(expanduser("~"), ".bokeh")
        if not exists(bokehdir):
            makedirs(bokehdir)
        return bokehdir
```

How can I fix this permission issue so that `bokeh` may be deployed on a server? I tried adding the `user=webdev` to the various `supervisord` program blocks to no avail. I have since removed the `user=webdev` from the `supervisor.conf` config for `redis`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own `app_document` decorator (see stock_app example) that allowed me to create a multi-user `bokeh session` and pass in a config directory, since that's where the error was being thrown.